# Finding equivalent resistance if each resistance is 100 ohms

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance, network

[image: r]

The method to follow here is wye delta transformation, the resistors across red and purple nodes are in series so 2R and using delta to wye in green-pink-blue, and pink-black-blue
after that there are many options to convert delta to Y or Y to delta like the pink Y or green Y, all leading to more complex circuit, what approach must be taken to get answer as fast a possible (answer 125 Ω), can it be solved using some other method?

Comment: It can be solved faster without a single delta-wye conversion, but that's because of symmetries of this specific circuit where all resistances are equal so it won't apply as a general case.

Comment: Are you in an exam?

Comment: Nah though i might it expect in exams this is a very lengthy question , i wanted a faster solution it took 20 minutes to get answer, which is too long because i used Wye Delta inefficiently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *what approach must be taken to get answer as fast a possible (answer
> 125 Ω), can it be solved using some other method?*

Here's a clue (we only give hints on homework sounding questions): -

[image]

In other words there can be no current flow in those resistors due to symmetry. But you can also short those resistors out to get the same answer: -

[image]

The answer is indeed 125 Ω. It took me 8 minutes of which 3 minutes was recognizing the symmetry and the implications.

Comment: Why there is no voltage across those horizontal resistors(and not vertical one) ?  Is that some theorem that shows how to short circuit the resistors ? And if the circuit had different resistances would this have worked if not then Which Wye delta to be done for efficient and fast solving.

Comment: It only works with equal value resistors. Vertical resistors will have a voltage across then when a voltage is applied between a and b.